# Name for a poset where incomparability is an equivalence relation

Tags: order-theory, equivalence-relations

Say I have a partial order $\leq$ on a set $S$. Let me write $a \sim b$ if $a$ and $b$ are incomparable under this order.

Is there a name for the following restriction on the partial order?

> $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

If this holds, then we can use the equivalence relation to partition $S$ into totally ordered subsets where $S_i \preceq S_j$ if and only if $a \leq b$ and $b \not\leq a$ for all $a \in S_i$ and $b \in S_j$. Each each $S_i$ contains only elements that are not comparable under the original partial order. So it seems like a nice property.

Comment: Since  $a\not\sim a,$ it ($\sim$) cannot be an equivalence relation, unless the poset is empty.

Comment: Even after correcting for Thomas' comment, the notion you'll get will just be equivalent to the poset being a disjoint union of linear orders. Such posets are not terribly interesting and so do not warrant a name. Certainly, most posets in nature are not of that type.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the condition "or a=b". @IttayWeiss, if you can convert that comment into an answer, I can accept it.